# Передать через ajax данные формы

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Хочу сделать на сайте добавление новостей без перезагрузки страницы. Вот форма:

```
<div class='field'>Введите заголовок:<br><input id="header_news" type='text' name='header' required value="" size='63'></div><br>
<div class='field'>Описание: <br><textarea id="description" name='description' value="" required id='bb_button' ></textarea></div><br>
<div class='field'>Категория:
    '<?php $query = mysqli_query($mysql,"SELECT * FROM `category` ORDER BY `category_name` ASC"); ?>'
<select id="subcategory" name='category'>
     '<?php while($row_3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){?>'
<option disabled value='<?php echo $row_3['id_category'];?>'><?php echo $row_3['category_name'];?>:</option>
    '<?php $row_2 = mysqli_query($mysql,"SELECT * FROM `subcategory` WHERE `id_category`=".$row_3['id_category']." ORDER BY `name_subcategory` ASC");
            while($row_4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($row_2)){?>
                <option  value="<?php echo $row_4['id_subcategory'];?>"><?php echo $row_4['name_subcategory'];?></option>
            <?php' }?>'
  </select></div><br>
        <div class='field'><input id="image" multiple="true" type='file' name='userfile' required accept='image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif,image/jpg' class='button'></div><br>
    <a href='http://blog.com/admin/news/news.php' title='Назад'>Назад</a> 
            <button id="clickButtonForm" class='button'>Добавить новость</button>
```

Вот код на  js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        // Делаем выборку кнопки из DOM дерева и заносим её в переменную
        var clickButtonForm = $("#clickButtonForm");
        // Составляем функцию которая срабатывает после события click на нашей кнопке
        clickButtonForm.click(function(){
            // Делаем выборку поля для ввода заголовка и заносим в переменную
            var Header = $("#header_news").val();
            // Делаем выборку поля для ввода описание и заносим в переменную
            var Description = $("#description").val();
            // Делаем выборку поля для ввода подкатегорий и заносим в переменную
            var Subcategory = $("#subcategory").val();
            // Делаем выборку поля для картинки и заносим в переменную
            var $image = $("#image");
            var fd = new FormData;
            fd.append('userfile',$image.prop('files')[0]);
            //Аякс запрос
            $.ajax({
                url: "1.php",
                data: {header: Header,description: Description,subcategory: Subcategory},
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
});
```

Как мне передать изображение вместе с другими данными? Знаю что если прописать

```
processData: false,
contentType: false,
```

То можно передать изображение, но тогда строковые данные не передадутся. Подскажите пожалуйста решение.

Comment: Писать код в таком стиле считалось неприличным ещё в 90-х. У вас испещрённая SQL-инъекциями вермишель из логики и HTML, так делать не надо.

Comment: Вы предлагаете в отдельном файле делать выборку и возвращать в HTML результат? Приведите пожалуйста пример

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `data` нужно передавать ваш объект `FormData` с нужными вами данными. С помощью `formData.append` добавьте заголовок, описание и другие нужные вам поля. Туда же добавляется файл. После этого отправляйте данные с параметрами `processData: false, contentType: false`.

Сейчас же у вас создаётся `FormData`, а потом в `data` передаётся левый объект `{header: Header,description: Description,subcategory: Subcategory}`.

Кстати, учтите, что это всё IE10+.

Comment: В смысле IE10+?

Comment: @КонстантинШиренков Файлы через AJAX — это современная фича, поддерживается только в IE10+.